# What are the possible causes for Google Drive File Copy failure (with insufficient permission [403] Error) despite the having required permissions?

Tags: c#, .net, google-drive-api

I tried to copy a Google Drive file into users root folder by impersonating the user with Service Credentials (Created a drive proxy with the Drive Scope) and I get the following Error:

```
Google.GoogleApiException: Google.Apis.Requests.RequestError
The user does not have sufficient permissions for this file. [403]
Errors [
    Message[The user does not have sufficient permissions for this file.] Location[ - ] Reason[insufficientFilePermissions] Domain[global]
]
```

When I debug the user has these permissions on the file.

```
ViewersCanCopyContent: True 

Capabilities.CanCopy: True
```

Can you please educate with any other things I can check for in order to be able to successfully copy the file?

Comment: How did you set up the users permission in the service account?  Did the gsuite admin set it up?

Comment: Have you tried a non-root folder?

Comment: Correct. Gsuite admin set it up.

Comment: @Sangbok Lee I will try this and update

Comment: Soo, any luck resolving this issue? I'm buping into the same error